# Rails Country_Select Gem In ReactJs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I'm trying not to do something stupid this morning but I'm finding myself love to use the HTML5 `data-*` attribute. I have installed [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) rails gem and it works great in `html.erb`, within a form:

```
<%= f.country_select :location, { priority_countries: ["GB", "US"], selected: "GB" } %>
```

My stupid way of pulling this into Reactjs would be:

**html.erb:**

```
<div id="foo" data-countries="<%= f.country_select :location, { priority_countries: ["GB", "US"], selected: "GB" } %>"></div>
```

For the above, I normally do this for methods.

**js.jsx:**

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    location: this.props.data.location
  }
},

geo: function(event) {
  this.setState({location: event.target.value});
},

render: function(){
  var bar = document.getElementById('foo');  

  return (
      <div>
        <select
           value={this.state.location}
           onChange={this.geo}
         >
           <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
           <option value="{bar.dataset.countries}">{bar.dataset.countries}</option>
         </select>
      </div>
    )
 }
```

In my views, all the countries are spitted out caused by the `data-countries` in the `html.erb`. Also in the rendered dropdown menu, I see the "Please Select" and `<select name=`

I know what I'm doing is 100% incorrect. Is there a correct way on doing this, if possible with this gem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it! Basically you'll need to [get the name from the country gem](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#getting-the-country-name-from-the-countries-gem):

**In your User Model:**

```
def country
  country = ISO3166::Country
  c = country.all
  c.map do |a| a.name end
end
```

**Now somewhere in the appropriate controller:**

```
def method_name
 c = User.new
 # Calling the method from user.rb
 @country = c.country
end
```

Since I'm using [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails), in my views:

```
<%= react_component('NewProject', { country: @country }) %>
```

**js.jsx:**

```
render: function(){
  var country = (c) => (<option key={c} value={c}>{c}</option>) 

  return (
      <div>
        <select
           value={this.state.location}
           onChange={this.geo}
         >
           <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
           {this.props.country.map(country)}
         </select>
      </div>
    )
```

Now I got my drop down. Hope this is useful to others!